# Swagger/Swashbuckle document POST with JSON

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I have a challenge with Swashbuckle or Swagger. I'm not sure if the problem is with Swagger or Swashbuckle. I have web api call, implemented both with the parameter as URI params, and with reading the content from the body of the request.

One is implemented like this:

```
    [Route("application/uri")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> Post([ModelBinder] Application application)
    {
        return await RegisterApplication(application);
    }
```

The other is implemented like this:

```
    [Route("loanapplication/json")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> PostByJson(Application application)
    {
        return await RegisterApplication(application); ;
    }
```

Both are using the same request objects, etc. The `ApplicationRequest` class includes an enum, `Purpose`. In the first service, the Swagger documentation is created beautifully, with nice documentation on each property in the `Application` type, like this:

[image: Swagger UI from URI-based service]

However, the second method, which uses standard HTTP body POST, generates a nice JSON example, but not with the allowable values in the enums. Is this a deficiency in Swashbuckle, in Swagger, or is it my lacking knowledge of how to use the tools?

This is what is generated from the second method:

[image: Swagger UI from POST Body based-service]

As you can see, the "Purpose" includes just the first possible enum value. And the contextual description (provided on the `ApplicationRequest` as Display attributes) are not displayed anywhere.

Comment: It should state the different enums in the "Model" type - The Schema is just an "example".

Comment: It does, but it doesn't show as available values, at it does in the "GET" example"

Comment: How did you manage to display the enum values as strings in the first example? In my case it always shows the integer values of the possible options for the enum??