# swaggerui return a list of available options

Tags: c#, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have the following model for a REST API end point i'm writing with SwaggerUI  using swashbuckle to self document:

```
{
 "Searchs": [
  {
  "Text": "SearchText1",
  "SearchType": "string"
  },
  {
  "Text": "SearchText2",
  "SearchType": "string"
  }
]
}
```

In this model there are N number of SearchTypes available for the user to use:

1. InFoo
2. NotInFoo
3. AllExceptFoo

I need to surface this list to the user in a friendly way, but can't see a way other than adding it to the XML comments, is there a better way to surface this to the user?

Comment: Which framework are you using - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, ServiceStack, ...?

Comment: I've update the question, @Helen, i'm using swashbuckle

Comment: Does this help? -> [Swagger/Swashbuckle list acceptable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338019/113116)